# Double Border in last item of list in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, user-interface, gridview

I am developing a UI in Flutter but when I put a border against my grid view item the last item repeats the border as seen in the screenshot. A sample code is also attached[image] [image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you include sample code snippet that will reproduce the same error

Comment: Sure, Sir, I have added it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided is not sufficient to give a suggestion. Please give us full sample code of atleast gridview to understand. And it is possible that their might be some glitch, it happen sometime, you can restart the device and run the app.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to see the double border anywhere. The screenshot you provided has a line below the picture of the tie. **I think it's the asset image, which has a line.**

**Your code looks good, have no problem in the code.**